# Why does running `jasmine` after `jasmine init` and `jasmine examples` do nothing?

Tags: node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I have globally installed jasmine by running `npm install jasmine -g`.

Running `jasmine -v` gives me

```
jasmine v2.5.0
jasmine-core v2.5.0
```

I have then, as per the [docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.5/node.html), run

```
jasmine init
jasmine examples
```

This created the expected `/spec` directory and the `spec/support/jasmine.json` file.

I am under the impression that if I now run `jasmine` I should see some test output in the console. Instead it simply thinks about it for a second and then does nothing.

I'm running node v4.5.0 on a Windows 7 machine in a Git Bash terminal. I've tried running it from the Windows cmd prompt as well but that doesn't work either.

Comment: i run into the same issue... (win10) `jasmine spec/jasmine_examples/PlayerSpec.js`doesn't work either

Comment: DId you get any solution for this? I have the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have finally got jasmine working via webpack and karma but I am still unable to run these example tests in the way described in the docs.

Comment: @MrMisterMan ok, then I opened an issue on jasmine, because it's unacceptable that doing exactly what the documentation says produces no feedback whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well jasmine does run, but it doesn't report anything when you run jasmine alone. *(you can confirm that by putting `console.log` inside `describe` functions and see that indeed it will log.)*

download the latest release, it will have an html file that you can run which will do all the work for you.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases

basically running jasmine requires a `boot.js` file for configurations. a `jasmine-html.js` file for the html reporter. you can figure out everything yourself by running the `SpecRunner.html`.

my personal preference is to use protractor and have the reporter configured in the protractor.config file.

if you want to run `jasmine` and have it run, you need to add your own boot.js and reporter, and loading them first thing before the spec in the `jasmine.json` file.

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "boot.js",
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in jasmine

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/90

Use version 2.4

```
npm install -g jasmine@~2.4
```