# Jasmine invocation returns absolutely nothing

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine

According to [jasmine documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine), I should be able to run the testsuite running `jasmine`.

[On this repository](http://github.com/stefanoborini/configurable-http-proxy) running jasmine in the test directory does absolutely nothing, even after exporting `JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH` to the `jasmine.json` file or passing it as argument. Note that even changing a test so that it fails, I get no result, no error, nothing. The command just returns to the prompt.

This is the content of the file

```
$ more jasmine.json 
{
  "spec_dir": "test",
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": false,
  "spec_files": ["*spec.js"]
}


(venv) sborini@MacBook-Pro:test (protocol-host-rewrite) [1 stash] $ ls `which jasmine`
/usr/local/bin/jasmine
```

package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.4.0-dev",
  "name": "configurable-http-proxy",
  "description": "A configurable-on-the-fly HTTP Proxy",
  "author": "Jupyter Developers",
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/jupyterhub/configurable-http-proxy.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "~2.9",
    "http-proxy": "~1.13.2",
    "lynx": "^0.2.0",
    "strftime": "~0.9",
    "winston": "~2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "jshint": "^2.9.2",
    "nyc": "^6.4.0",
    "request": "~2",
    "ws": "^1.1"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "files": [
    "index.js",
    "lib/configproxy.js",
    "lib/trie.js",
    "lib/error/*.html",
    "bin/configurable-http-proxy"
  ],
  "bin": {
    "configurable-http-proxy": "bin/configurable-http-proxy"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "jshint": "jshint bin/ lib/ test/",
    "test": "nyc jasmine JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=test/jasmine.json",
    "coverage-html": "nyc report --reporter=html",
    "codecov": "nyc report --reporter=lcov && codecov"
  }
}
```

Note that invoking it with `npm run test` does produce the output of the coverage, but if I err a test, It just produces the following output

```
(venv) sborini@MacBook-Pro:configurable-http-proxy (protocol-host-rewrite) [1 stash] $ npm run test

> configurable-http-proxy@1.4.0-dev test /Users/sborini/Work/github/stefanoborini/configurable-http-proxy
> nyc jasmine JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=test/jasmine.json

-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File             |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
 lib/            |     89.9 |       75 |    83.58 |    90.36 |                |
  configproxy.js |    87.01 |    64.81 |    84.78 |     87.6 |... 436,437,444 |
  testutil.js    |    93.83 |    93.75 |    73.33 |    93.83 |... 114,116,117 |
  trie.js        |    96.72 |       95 |      100 |    96.72 |          15,19 |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files        |     89.9 |       75 |    83.58 |    90.36 |                |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|


npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.10.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "test"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! configurable-http-proxy@1.4.0-dev test: `nyc jasmine JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=test/jasmine.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the configurable-http-proxy@1.4.0-dev test script 'nyc jasmine JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=test/jasmine.json'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the configurable-http-proxy package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     nyc jasmine JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=test/jasmine.json
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs configurable-http-proxy
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls configurable-http-proxy
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/sborini/Work/github/stefanoborini/configurable-http-proxy/npm-debug.log
```

Which does not tell me anything about the actual failing test.

Comment: Can you show us what `which jasmine` gives you from bash, and what your `package.json` looks like?

Comment: @broguinn done.

Comment: Where do you set the `JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH`? Otherwise, it's going to look for `jasmine.json` in `spec/support`.

Comment: Is your spec folder in the root of your project?

Comment: @broguinn at the bash prompt. I invoked the exact line that is in the package.json without the nyc

Comment: @alex I don't have any spec folder (I don't even know what it is) but invoking npm run test seems to work, except that I don't see any failure, just a coverage report and a noisy error that doesn't say what test has failed.

Comment: Note that a similar issue is asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272688/why-does-running-jasmine-after-jasmine-init-and-jasmine-examples-do-nothin?rq=1), again without answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To all the googlers, it's a bug in jasmine.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/90

Install and use the old version:

```
npm install jasmine@~2.4
```

This works.

Comment: Once again, confirming that SO has a completely toxic community. I posted this question with full information of what I can possibly know about an environment I have no experience about and the only thing I got was downvotes.

Comment: Don't worry bud. I upvoted to counter-act those down votes. Keep developing :)